# How to make each object in array its own element

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

[image]I have an array of objects that I am using to make a table in Angular. The table works great and adds the data correctly. I am now wanting to be able to edit each object within the table. For example if I wanted to change John Smiths name. How would I make each object in the array its own element so that I can make changes to them individually? Right now if I check 'this.dataFromQuery' it brings back the entire result.

```
Array: `[
  { first_name: 'John ', last_name: 'Smith', jobNumber: 123 },
  { first_name: 'Smith', last_name: 'John', jobNumber: 321 },
  { first_name: 'Alex', last_name: 'Mason', jobNumber: 10101 },
  { first_name: 'Mason', last_name: 'Alex', jobNumber: 100101 }
]`
```

Table HTML `

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataFromQuery.result" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.first_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.last_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="job_Number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Job Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.jobNumber}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button  (click)="openDialog()" mat-mini-fab color="primary" aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>"
```

`

TS

```
     getDataFromAPi(){
    this.service.showDataToClient().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("Query Results ", response)
      this.dataFromQuery = response
      return this.dataFromQuery.result
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("error", error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: So, you need `openDialog` to receive the `element` of the row you clicked the button? If so, just pass it in (`(click)="openDialog(element)"`).

Comment: @PhilippMeissner. Welp that was way simpler than I thought it would be...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the "current" row element at hand. All you need to do ti is pass it into the click handler and edit the signature of the method:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataFromQuery.result" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    ...
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <!--- Here you have the row data as "element". Pass it to the "click" handler next line: -->
        <button  (click)="openDialog(element)" mat-mini-fab color="primary" aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>  
  </table>"
```

Inside your .ts file you need to edit the signature:

```
openDialog(element: SomeType) {}
```